# I ask you to find a game, then a place in the game and finally make a screenshot

Tags: riddle, knowledge, board-games, game-theory, word-game

1. **Clues to find the game:**

I drive a lot.

Everything I eat tends to poison me.

Passion neon.

Do you like kombucha?

2. **Clue for location in the game:**

boys, boys, boys (I’m looking for a good time)

3. **Clue for capture (linked to location):**

iron bar

> Who am I and where?

You will not find it.

Comment: Are you sure that this is a game *about* words? Or that this is *about* the math/logic of game theory? Or that this is a table-top board game (not a videogame as seems implied)?

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer:

The game is:

> Oregon Trail

Because

> You drive a wagon 
>  You get dysentery a lot 
>  The Oregon Ducks football uniform has neon pink highlights 
>  There is a modern version of the game put out by Travel Oregon where you can buy Kombucha as a starting item, and kombucha is popular in Oregon (Oregon is the state tied for [third lowest](https://www.boochnews.com/2020/06/22/a-statistical-analysis-of-kombucha-brands-in-the-usa/) population per kombucha brewery, not counting DC).